# My evernote-mode doesn't work now

Tags: emacs, org-mode, evernote

I input the correct user and passwd, but emacs shows me that

> evernote::EDAM::Error::EDANUserException (parameter: consumerKey errorCode: INVALID_AUTH)

I used 0.41 version of evernote-mode ,and have done all setup.

the file "Evernote-Client-Output" displayed this message:

> ((class . ErrorReply)(result_code . 8)(command_id . 7)(message . "Evernote::EDAM::Error::EDAMUserException (parameter: consumerKey errorCode: INVALID_AUTH)"))

please tell me how to handle this error. thanks.

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Comment: me too, it always say invalid authentication although i put correct password

Answer (score 4):

evernote-mode probably needs to be updated to make use of either OAuth or developer tokens. More info [here](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

evernote-mode has been updated with oauth and using developer tokens by pymander, see  [here](https://github.com/pymander/evernote-mode). But 
there is known issues when opening existing notebooks due to invalid gdbm, see the outstanding issues in the repo. The error is fixed in a recent folked [repo](https://github.com/optidatascience/evernote-mode).

Answer (score 0):

No longer maintained. See [issue #38](https://github.com/pymander/evernote-mode/issues/38#issuecomment-1431856227).